# Deserialize json object array with json.net

Tags: c#, json

I want to deserialize json object array. I'm stuck.
I can not figure out how to get it to be happy with the provided structure.
Doing something a CustomerList (below) results in a "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array" exception.

I tried almost anything

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleAppProva
{
    class Program
    {
        public class CustomerJson
        {
            [JsonProperty("IdPostazionee")]
            public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        }

        public class Customer
        {
            [JsonProperty("abc")]
            public string Firstname { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("def")]
            public string Lastname { get; set; }

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = "{'IdPostazione':'1','StatoAutoma':'2','OriginalURL':'3','OriginalTitle':'lol','ChronicID':'xd'}";

            dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", dynObj.IdPostazione, dynObj.StatoAutoma, dynObj.OriginalURL);

            string jsoon = "{'IdPostazionee':['abc':'123','def':'456']}";

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to see in console the values of the array : 123 , 456.

IdPostazionee is the array. abc, def are the fields

Comment: `{'IdPostazionee':['abc':'123','def':'456']}` is malformed JSON.  And even if I change the single-quotes to double quotes like so: `{"IdPostazionee": ["abc": "123", "def": "456"]}` it is still not well formed.  Upload to https://jsonlint.com/ to confirm.  A JSON array should contain comma-separated values only, not name : value pairs.

Comment: _"I'm expecting to see in console the values of the array : 123 , 456."_ How? Taking into account the code provided, this is impossible.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `{"IdPostazionee": {"abc": "123", "def": "456"}}` which is well-formed?  Of course `IdPostazionee` is now an object not an array (and should be deserializable to your model).

Comment: @dbc Look at the code, the output will not be as expected, whatever the content of `jsoon` is.

Comment: I suggest you construct an object as you expect it to be and serialize it. Then look at the resulting json and compare it to the one you have in your example. I also suspect, this is not the complete code of yours. Just setting a string variable won't do anything. Please provide an [mcve], that actually resembles your real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following JSON that you posted is invalid:

```
{
    'IdPostazionee': ['abc': '123', 'def': '456']
}
```

I guess it should be:

```
{
    "IdPostazionee": [{
        "abc": "123",
        "def": "456"
    }]
}
```

Or better:

```
{
    "IdPostazionee": {
        "abc": "123",
        "def": "456"
    }
}
```

The following code should work:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp11
{
    class Program
    {
        public class CustomerJson
        {
            [JsonProperty("IdPostazionee")]
            public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        }

        public class Customer
        {
            [JsonProperty("abc")]
            public string Firstname { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("def")]
            public string Lastname { get; set; }

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = "{'IdPostazione':'1','StatoAutoma':'2','OriginalURL':'3','OriginalTitle':'lol','ChronicID':'xd'}";

            dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", dynObj.IdPostazione, dynObj.StatoAutoma, dynObj.OriginalURL);

            string jsoon = "{'IdPostazionee': {'abc':'123','def':'456'}}";

            var customerJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerJson>(jsoon);

            Console.WriteLine(customerJson.Customer.Firstname);
            Console.WriteLine(customerJson.Customer.Lastname);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While that may be true, OP is deserializing a completely different one.

Comment: @Fildor, I really don't understand you comment. The first piece of code works, and I guess the OP needs to deserialize the last json into `CustomerJson` class. Please could you clarify?

Comment: Yes, he needs to do so. But does not. Implementing your changes will not change the result without also changing the code.

Comment: After Edit: That's what I meant +1